# How do I identify and then isolate a Gene that codes for a particular observable phenotype

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, gene

How do I identify and then isolate a Gene that codes for a particular observable phenotype. It is a novel bacteria and I do not know the gene sequence or the protein that it codes for.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Finish reading the Tour (you haven’t) and read our policy on homework questions. The repost when you can satisfy the criteria for allowable homework questions.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_genetics